# Tree diagram with nodes information

Tags: nodes, tikz-trees

I have this tree diagram but I need to add extra information in each node (stuff like 7+2+3=12) so I need to make the node larger for the info to fit in nicely. How can I write this kind of information on the nodes? I don't need it right now but I would like to know if it is possible to add info to the edges as well. Thank you in advance.

```
level/.style={sibling distance=30mm/#1},
edge from parent/.style={->,draw}   % <----
                        ]
\node [circle,draw] {A}
    child {node [circle,draw] {B}
        child {node [circle,draw] {F}}
    }
    child {node [circle,draw] {C}
        child {node [circle,draw] {D}
            child {node [circle,draw] {G}
                child {node [circle,draw] {F}
                    child {node [circle,draw] {H}}
                }
                child {node [circle,draw] {H}}
            }
        }
        child {node [circle,draw] {E}
            child {node [circle,draw] {F}}
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: the above fragment of code will not compile-- please upload a minimal code MWE which compiles and shows the problem

Comment: Does need to be those information inside circle or can be beside circle (as label)?

Comment: Hi @Zarko I would prefer the info to be inside the circles

Comment: That means that you can simple ad to nodes contents this information. For example as  `child {node [circle,draw] {F, end of branch}}`.  Of course with this circles become large and will differ to each other according to nodes contents Please be so kind and provide sketch, how one such node with additional information should to be.

Comment: Hello @Zarko. The extra information should appear below the node identifier (i.e. below the capital letter) and the font size should be smaller than the one of the node identifier. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are willing to consider the following changes in your tree design:

- instead of `tikz` tree to use `forest`
- replace circles with rectangles with rounded corners
- text in nodes can be multiline
- additional information have smaller font size and eventually different color

than possible solution can be:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand\main{\large\color{black}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    draw, rounded corners=1ex, minimum width=5em,
    font=\scriptsize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
    text=gray,
    text badly centered,
% tree
    edge = {-Straight Barb},
    anchor=north,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep=6mm,
    where level=0{s sep=7mm}{s sep=5mm},
tier/.option = level,
            }
[\makecell{\main A\\
            some long initial\\
            text, root node}
    [\makecell{\main B\\
                $7 + 2 + 3 = 12$}
        [\main F]
    ]
    [\makecell{\main C\\
                huh!}
        [\main  D
            [\main G
                [\makecell{\main F\\
                            $1+2=3$}
                    [\makecell{\main H\\
                                end of\\ branch}]
                ]
                [\makecell{\main H\\
                            end of\\ branch}]
            ]
        ]
        [\makecell{\main E\\
                    $1+2=3$}
            [\makecell{\main F\\
                        end}]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]