# Tikz trees: How to add multiple lines to terminal nodes to avoid overlapping nodes

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-node

The text of my terminal nodes for my tree is overlapping.  Does anyone know how to place the labels on multiple lines? I checked stackoverflow but did not find a solution.  I can space out the tree but I prefer to add a second line to the node because eventually, the spacing can only go so far.

I tried adding a double backslash to the text but it created an error message.  Does anyone have suggestions?  Below is my code and images of what I am trying to do (before and ideally after)

Thank you.

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1.5] 
\tikzstyle{solid node} =[circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black]
\tikzstyle{hollow node}=[circle,draw,inner sep=1.5]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=2.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=1cm]

\node(0)[hollow node,label=above:{},align=left]{} 
child{node[solid node]{}
    child{node[hollow node,label=below,align=left:{appleJacks are great \\ appleJacks are great}]{} edge from parent node[left]{a}}
    child{node[hollow node,label=below:{appleJacks are great, \\ appleJacks are great}]{} edge from parent node[right]{b}}
    edge from parent node[left,xshift=-5]{action1}
}
child{node[solid node]{}
    child{node[hollow node,label=below:{appleJacks are great, appleJacks are great}]{} edge from parent node[left]{a}}
    child{node[hollow node,label=below:{appleJacks are great, appleJacks are great}]{} edge from parent node[right]{b}}
    edge from parent node[right,xshift=5]{action2}
};
\draw[dashed, label=above right:{my label}](0-1)to(0-2);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You'll need `align=center` (or any other alignment) or a `text width` to be able to use ``\\`` in a node. See [Q123671](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671)

Comment: I added align=left and \\ and latex program (I updated my code) printed an error message.  Some of the examples in the link you provided work but when I incorporate them into my tree code, they do not.  My tree code works except for this issue.

Comment: Same as with your other [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665791/tikz-trees-how-to-add-label-to-dashed-information-set#comment1655616_665791). These things need to be the options of the `label`. Either as part of the the `every label` style or directly between the `[` and `]` of your label. The latter usually needs to have the whole argument enclosed in braces. [The full syntax is `label={[<options>]<direction>:<text>}`.](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase sibling distance at level 1:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,
every label/.append style = {align=center},
 solid node/.style = {circle,draw,fill=black,inner sep=1.5pt},
hollow node/.style = {circle,draw,inner sep=1.5pt},
level distance = 15mm,
level 1/.style = {sibling distance=5cm},
level 2/.style = {sibling distance=2.5cm},
lbl/.style = {pos=0.55, anchor=south #1, font=\footnotesize},
                    ]
\node(0)[hollow node]{}
    child{node[solid node]{}
        child{node[hollow node,label=below:{appleJacks are great \\ appleJacks are great}] {}
             edge from parent node[lbl=east]{a}}
        child{node[hollow node,label=below:{appleJacks are great, \\ appleJacks are great}]{}
            edge from parent node[lbl=west]{b}}
        edge from parent node[lbl=east]{action1}
        }
    child{node[solid node]{}
        child{node[hollow node,label=below:{appleJacks are great,\\ appleJacks are great}]{} 
            edge from parent node[lbl=east]{a}}
        child{node[hollow node,label=below:{appleJacks are great,\\ appleJacks are great}]{} 
            edge from parent node[lbl=west]{b}}
        edge from parent node[lbl=west]{action2}
        };
\draw[dashed](0-1) to["my label"] (0-2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
For cases when you like to draw tres with more levels, the use of the `forest` package can be handy. Code for above tree cna be writen asČ

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    circle, draw, minimum size=6pt, inner sep=0pt,
/tikz/N/.style = {rectangle, draw=none, 
                  font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                  inner ysep=4pt, inner xsep=0pt,
                  text width=8.8em, align=center
                 },
% tree
if level = 2{N, 
             child anchor=north,
             edge=-{Circle[open, length=6pt]} }
            {-},
   l sep = 12mm,
   s sep = 2mm,
%tier/.option = level,
%% edge labels
/tikz/ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
              pos=0.5, node font=\scriptsize,
              inner sep=2pt, anchor=south #1},
       EL/.style = {% Edge Label
            if n=1{edge label={node[ELS=east]{#1}}}
                  {edge label={node[ELS=west]{#1}}}},
           }
[   
    [ , fill, name=A, EL=action 1
        [appleJacks are great appleJacks are great,
         EL=$a$
        ]
        [appleJacks are great appleJacks are great,
         EL=$b$,
        ]
    ]
    [ , fill, name=B, EL=action 2
        [appleJacks are great appleJacks are great,
         EL=$a$,
        ]
        [appleJacks are great appleJacks are great,
         EL=$b$,
        ]
    ]
]
\draw[dashed]   (A) to [ELS, "my label"] (B);
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

You can observe, that now nodes at bottom level are rectangles (which replace `label` in above MWE) and the style of edges to this nodes is changes to `edge=-{Circle[open, length=6pt]}`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Zarko, that works! I have one more question, - Currently it is 2 layers, how can I make it three layers (8 terminal nodes)?

Comment: I finally figured out how to add a third layer.  Thank you very much for taking the time to assist me with this problem that I spent hours on even after looking at tikz documentation.

Comment: If you have more layers, I would look to `forest` package, which is dedicated for drawing/writing of trees. In your case its main advantage is, that it can define minimal distance between nodes and not need any care about `sibling distance`. At more layers you should be aware that tree should be sufficient small that can be placed  on page (problem can happen even at `landscape` page orientation). For an example of `forest` six layer tree see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586227/tree-diagram-with-nodes-information/586253#586253.